# How does the substitution theorem fail in this case?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I have a very basic question on the substitution rule for definite integrals.
Suppose I want to evaluate
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^{1}x\ \text{d}x
\end{equation}
with the substitution $x=\varphi(u)=u^2$, so that $\text{d}x = 2u\ \text{d}u$. The real problem here are the integration extremes, since the function $\varphi$ is not injective. I am anyway unable to see which hypothesis of the substitution theorem is not satisfied, could please someone help me?

Comment: Since $x\in[-1,1]$, and since $u^2\ge 0$, does the substitution even make sense?

Comment: the problem is a theoretical one, i.e. to see where the theorem fails...

Comment: @marcotrevi $-1$ isn't even in the range of $\varphi$

Comment: of course, but could you please show me how the hypothesis of the theorem is not satisfied? I cannot do it.

Comment: eli5 please, because I'm just not getting it, I don't know why.

Comment: Why don't you make it simple for us, and **state** for us the exact theorem that you're using. "The substitution theorem" is not a universally agreed-upon thing (as the answers you've gotten have shown).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the substitution theorem that I know and love is this:
$$
\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t) ~ dt = \int_a^b f(g(x)) g'(x) ~dx
$$
where $g$ must be differentiable on the interval $[a, b]$, and all terms must be defined (i.e. the domain of $f$ must contain $g([a, b])$, for instance).

I don't see how this theorem applies to your integral at all.

You're probably applying the "inverse substitution theorem", which you can state by replacing $g$, in the theorem above, with $h^{-1}$. But that theorem only applies when the function $h$ is invertible, and when (once again) all terms are defined (i.e., there are restrictions on the relations between the upper and lower limits of the two integrals and the domain/codomain of $h$).

**Post-comment addition**

Let me try to work from what I've said above to the revised theorem for you.

Start from
$$
\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t) ~ dt = \int_a^b f(g(x)) g'(x) ~dx
$$
Assume $g$ is invertible, with inverse $h$. If $g(a) = A$ and $g(b) = B$, then $h(A) = a$ and $h(B) = b$. So we can rewrite
$$
\int_{A}^{B} f(t) ~ dt = \int_{h(A)}^{h(B)} f(g(x)) g'(x) ~dx
$$
Now let's do a little more, and substitute $h^{-1}$ for $g$:

> $$ \int_{A}^{B} f(t) ~ dt = \int_{h(A)}^{h(B)} f(h^{-1}(x) (h^{-1})'(x) ~dx $$

Now in doing these substitutions, I've assumed two things in addition to the assumptions of the ordinary substitution rule:

1. $g$, restricted to the interval $[a, b]$, is invertible
2. The numbers $A$ and $B$ are in the image $g([a, b])$.

If we apply this theorem to compute, say 
$$
\int_0^8 t^\frac{2}{3} ~ dt
$$
by letting $t = s^3$, the "just substitute" algebra looks like this:
\begin{align}
dt &= 3s^2 ds\\
\int_0^8 t^\frac{2}{3} ~ dt 
&= \int_0^2 (s^3)^\frac{2}{3} 3 s^2 ~ ds\\
&= \int_0^2 (s^2) 3 s^2 ~ ds\\
&= \int_0^2 3 s^4 ~ ds\\
&= \left. \frac{3}{5} s^5 \right|_0^2\\
&= \frac{3}{5} 2^5.
\end{align}
[where I may have gotten the algebra wrong, of course!]

What we're really doing is saying that 
$$
h^{-1}(s) = t
$$
so that
$$
h(s) = s^\frac{1}{3}
$$
and 
$$
h^{-1}(s) = s^3.
$$

Now applying the theorem as written in the displayed box above, we have $A = 0, B = 8, a = 0, b = h(8) = 2$, and $f(t) = t^\frac{2}{3}$. So we get
\begin{align}
\int_0^8 t^\frac{2}{3} ~ dt 
&= \int_{h(A)}^{h(B)} f(h^{-1}(x)) (h^{-1})'(x) ~dx \\
&= \int_{h(A)}^{h(B)} (h^{-1}(x))^\frac{2}{3} (h^{-1})'(x) ~dx
\end{align}
Recalling that $h^{-1}(s) = s^3$, we have that its derivative is $3s^2$, so 
\begin{align}
\int_0^8 t^\frac{2}{3} ~ dt 
&= \int_{h(A)}^{h(B)} f(h^{-1}(x)) (h^{-1})'(x) ~dx \\
&= \int_{h(A)}^{h(B)} (x^3)^\frac{2}{3} \cdot 3x^2 ~dx\\
&= \int_{0}^{2} x^2 \cdot 3x^2 ~dx
\end{align}
which is what we got with the "just do the substitution" thing before.

Now there's actually something subtle: it turns out that there's a more general version of the theorem that doesn't actually require $h$ to be invertible, so that you can sometimes do substitutions like $x = u^3 - u, dx = 3u^2 - 1$. But I don't have the time or energy to write out the details. Fortunately for me, Michael Spivak has already done so, beautifully, in his book *Calculus*. I encourage you to take a look at the chapter on methods of integration for the details.

Comment: Actually the biggest problem is correctly stating it. I see the point now: i thought that the two theorems were actually the same one.

Answer (score 3):

There are to problems here:

- your function $\varphi$ is not injective;
- not all points of $[-1,1]$ are of the form $\varphi(x)$ for some $x$.

Note that if you do the some thing with the integral$$\int_0^1x\,\mathrm dx,\tag1$$then none of these problems occur and all goes well. In other words, the integral $(1)$ is indeed equal to$$\int_0^12u^3\,\mathrm du.$$

Comment: but $\varphi$ need not be injective, following the theorem's statement.

Comment: @marcotrevi When you are using the theorem under the form$$\int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)}f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^bf\bigl(\varphi(y)\bigr)\varphi'(y)\,\mathrm dy,$$we don't need to assume that hypothesis. But that is *not* what you do when you do $x=\varphi(y)$. In this case, what we are really doing is to apply the previous expression using $\varphi^{-1}$. And an inverse is always injective. This is very well explained is Spivak's *Calculus*.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Jose, there is no need to impose the condition that $\phi$ be injective.  [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_single_variable) is a link to an article which discusses integration by substitution.  Clearly, the only problem here is that there fails to exist a number $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi(a)=a^2<0$.

Answer (score 3):

Integration by substitution:
$$\int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)} f(x) \ \mathrm dx = \int_a^b f(\varphi(t))\varphi'(t) \ \mathrm dt$$

The substitution is "$x = \varphi(t)$".

In this case, you want $x = \varphi(t) = t^2$.

Then, you need to find $a$ such that $\varphi(a) = -1$ and $b$ such that $\varphi(b) = 1$, but the former is clearly impossible.